# App Center not updating

Tags: updates, appcenter

For some reasons, the app center is no longer checking if my apps are up to date and it does not give me the automatic update as before. I am now back the old `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` but the automatic update was quite nice. Any idea why this stopped?